# What is the proper way to center this button?

Tags: html, css

I have this button on my page that is currently aligned to the left side of my screen but I want it to be in the middle. What would be the proper way to achieve this?

html

```
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

css

```
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;

    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: use `text-align:center; display: inline-block` on his parent. You should share all relevant code for your problem

Comment: Get rid of the padding... and set align: center.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `wrapper` with `text-align: center;` and `position` the button to place it in center:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not centered! It's to far to the right. The `position: absolute;` brakes the horizontal centering (https://jsfiddle.net/p1ztx2ga/) if you remove it (https://jsfiddle.net/p1ztx2ga/1/) then it's at least centered horizontally. In short `position:absolute;` does not work nicely with `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

you have to put button in div

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
  <button class="button">Button</button>
<div>
```

You can check here [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eK22Y/)

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS3 these days should be the way to go. With this also the size of the element (button) does not matter.

```css
.button {
    /* THE MAGIC */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    /* YOUR STYLINGS FROM QUESTION */
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

If you want to center both horizontally and vertically it's almost the same

```css
.button {
    /* THE MAGIC */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* YOUR STYLINGS FROM QUESTION */
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: dont get me wrong but its too big and confusing to remember alll this ..just for simple problem ...of centering button in center

Comment: @PranayRana this is all there is: `position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` not really so much.

Comment: ok , i got confuse with other properties

Comment: @PranayRana I see, I should put the relevant changes to the top to make that more clear. Thank you!